# How to find a user Instagram uid and uidb36?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api, uid

Now I am testing Instagram.

How to find any user Instagram uid or uidb36?

I am try to reset my password via Email address, Instagram server send me two link one short link and another is very long link.

example:

short link

1. `https://www.instagram.com/_n/emaillogin?uid=pwar8ac&token=IBo6y9&auto_send=0`

long link

2. `https://instagram.com/accounts/password/reset/confirm/?uidb36=pwar8ac&token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:one_click_login_email&v=264.0.0.22.106&s=one_click_login_email`

Many times, I try to request reset my password token as generate new token of every 24 hr (daily one time reset your password........ (now, I am try a different account).

But I not focus token, we only focus uid... (user id) "uid=pwar8ac" or uidb36 "?uidb36=pwar8ac", how to find any user uid.

Help.....

How to find any user uid? Any API endpoint showing user uid=xxx or uidb36=xxx?

How to find any user uid?

Any API endpoint showing user uid or uidb36 ( ..\emaillogin??uid or ../password/reset/confirm/?uidb36=?uid ??? )

Where to find that?

Please help me.

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74919853/how-to-find-any-user-instagram-uid-and-uidb36

Answer (score 0):

I was searching the same thing and found a API endpoint which returns the userid. The point is to convert that user id (which is a number) to base36.

API: https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/users/web_profile_info/?username=

You need to add X-IG-App-ID to the header. You can find it in any Instagram web api request. You can find the id inside user>id

Then convert to base36. Ex: UserId: 1511897692, uid: p057q4

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for providing an answer. I've removed the question from your answer, given answers should be only used to answer the question, see [answer]. If you have another, possibly related question, please [ask it as a separate question](/questions/ask). You can link back to this one in case you think that helps.